# phpmailer attachment to multiple mails

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I have a form where a user can send a injury to the website operator and the user can attach some images to this mail. The mail goes to the operator and as a confirmation to the user.
I use the library PHPmailer and everything works fine but that the attachment is only attached to one email and not to both.

I have a foreach loop for the fileupload and I save the filepath and name in vars and use the again in a var with `addAttachment();` Than I call this variable in my mails.
Ist is `Line 181` in my pastebin:

```
https://pastebin.com/v7jwbZev
```

I have a $mail->ClearAttachments(); after the first mail sending but it should not be the problem because I fill the `$file`before it is called.
I would really appreacheate if some one can help me?

Cheers

Comment: Try using a `CC` or `BCC` instead of duplicating the email. Or I believe you can give `$Mail->to()` an array of addresses and it will be sent to them all.

Comment: There is no `to()` method in PHPMailer. Add addresses by calling `addAddress()` on each one; it does not accept arrays.

Comment: You're not handling uploaded files safely in the way the PHP docs tell you to. Look at [the multiple file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_multiple_file_upload.phps) for how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the uploaded files to PHPMailer before the first send (though see my comment on doing it safely). You are then calling `clearAttachments()`, which does indeed remove the attachments, so when you call `send` the second time, there are no attachments to send.

The easiest fix for this is simply not to call `clearAttachments()` at all - then the attachments will remain in pace for the second message. You don't need to call any of the `clear*` functions the second time because the instance goes out of scope and so gets destroyed anyway.